# Message: Call to a member function result_array() on a non-object

Tags: codeigniter

I'm new to Codeigniter and I'm still getting my head around the DB interaction. I can't work out why this is giving me an error, I presume it's something with the query but I can run it fine without errors directly against the DB. Any ideas?

```
public function getLastSafetyTraining()
    {

        $query = "SELECT entry_date as date, field_id_108 as instructor FROM exp_channel_titles t, exp_channel_data d WHERE t.channel_id = 27 AND t.entry_id = d.entry_id";

        $result = $this->db->query($query);

        foreach ($result->result_array() as $row)
        {
            echo $row['date'];
            echo $row['instructor'];
        }

    }
```

Adding successful DB call:

```
public function getListOfInstructors()
    {
        $query = $this->db->select('member_id, email, group_id')
                            ->where('group_id >', 7)
                            ->limit(10, 20)
                            ->get('exp_members');

        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is likely due to the fact that the query (and resulting result() object) are empty. Ensure that the query actually returns at least one record before attempting to use the result() object:

```
if($query->num_rows() > 0){
    return $query->result(); //this thing has to be done in model
}
```

Actually that echo part has to be done in view only you have to do is return result to controller 
load above model in controller and call model function as

```
$var = $this->model->function();
```

manipulate result and then pass data to view and echo there

In more clear words Dont echo anything in model[where all query part is done] from model only return result of query to ensure that we used if condition and return the result to controller.

This model has to be loaded in controller and get those return value from model so we used 
$this->load->model('nameof model');

and then get those value and save it in variable as

```
$var = $this->model->function(); //now pass this to view after manipulating it as and echo in view
```

in your model you have to do like  this

```
public function getLastSafetyTraining()
    {

        $query = "SELECT entry_date as date, field_id_108 as instructor FROM exp_channel_titles t, exp_channel_data d WHERE t.channel_id = 27 AND t.entry_id = d.entry_id";

        $result = $this->db->query($query);
       $count = count($result);

    if(empty($count) || $count > 1)
    {
        $log = 0;
        return $log ;
    }
    else
    {
        return $result;
    }



    }
```

your controller

```
public function getListOfInstructors()
    {
       $this->load->model('Name of your model');
            $result = $this->Name_of_model->Name_of_function_of_model();
            if($result==0) {
                echo "Nothing found";
                }
                else {
                    $data['var']=$result;
                    $this->load->view('header');
                    $this->load->view("your view", $data);
                }



    }
```

Comment: You guys are right, I am getting an empty result set. However I can run that query via PHPMyAdmin and get results so what is wrong with the query in CI?

Comment: @user1684180 strange did you loaded the database configuration properly try to print your query as print_r($query);

Comment: Yep, as my controller is calling a model function right before this that is returning values from the database. I'll update the original post to include this.

Comment: @user1684180 you have done it in wrong way i will just update my answer how to do

Comment: @user1684180 where this function getListOfInstructors() is in model or controller

Comment: OK, I finally worked out what the issue was. I was connecting to the wrong database. Doh!

Comment: @user1684180 bah... :) how could you that ;p

Answer (score 0):

Can you modify your code as following:

```
public function getLastSafetyTraining()
    {

        $query = "SELECT entry_date as date, field_id_108 as instructor FROM exp_channel_titles t, exp_channel_data d WHERE t.channel_id = 27 AND t.entry_id = d.entry_id";

        $result = $this->db->query($query);

        print_r($result); die; // this is added line for debug


        foreach ($result->result_array() as $row)
        {
            echo $row['date'];
            echo $row['instructor'];
        }

    }
```

You can debug by doing this, if you can't Write what output prints here and I will give exact problem of your code.